Related list not refreshing using LWC
I have LWC code that creates new record and redirects it to related list. Below is the code that I have used to redirect to related list. Its redirects, but does not refresh the related list. Can someone please help me in getting the related list refreshed once the its redirected.
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

handleSubmit() {
this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
this.dispatchEvent(
    new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Success',
        message: 'Record successfully created',
        variant: 'success',
    }),
);
// Navigate to the related list
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: 'Abc__c',
        actionName: 'list',
    },
    state: {       
            filterName: 'All' 
        },
});
}

Thanks,
SFDC dev

May you use RefreshView before navigating to the List View? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html

thanks for the reply @Luisma Whatakuai. I used it but its not refreshing the list view with and not showing the new record that is created in the list view. Once I refresh the browser it shows the new record  in the list view. I have updated my code in the question how i used Refresh View.

I have no tried but maybe you can generate url first, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation and then after generating, navigate to the url. it may reload the page, although it may not be seamless refreshed but browser refreshed.
